# How to install SonataIntlBundle with composer?

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, composer-php, symfony-sonata, intl

I read [the documentation](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/reference/installation.html) but when I do this :

```
php composer.phar require sonata-project/intl-bundle
```

I have this message in my console :5

```
Please provide a version constraint for the sonata-project/intl-bundle requirement:
```

So I tried "master" or "2.*" but this doesn't work.

I'm using Symfony 2.1.7 and PHP 5.4.3, with the php_intl extension.

If someone can help me... Thanks !

Comment: Just add in your comoser.json file: "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "dev-master" inside "require" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [their package](https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/intl-bundle) to determine which version of the package you want. In this case, you only have a `dev-master` version, so you should run this:

```
$ php composer.phar require sonata-project/intl-bundle:dev-master
```

For a longer answer on how to install bundles with composer, see [this answer on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13340180/1149495)